# Why isn't a package showing showing for update?

Tags: composer, magento2.3.5-p2

Using composer I would like to update xtento/productexport I am on version 2.9.0 and the most recent version is 2.14.4. When I run composer outdated it doesn't show that it needs an update. In order to update it I looked in their docs and it says run this command-

composer update xtento/productexport --with-all-dependencies

When I run that command I get this-

```
xtento/productexport 2.9.0 requires php ~5.5.22|~5.6.0|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0|~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.24) does not satisfy that requirement
```

So I switch to php 7.2 and get this-

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.4.1].
- magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.1 requires php ~7.3.0||~7.4.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.34) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Xtento does not give lifetime updates so they were not allowing me to update.